# facebook applications resting with the wall

Tags: facebook

i have built apps that reside on apps.facebook.com but i want to built something that can be used in a facebook wall like the first link here-

http://www.facebook.com/pages/TXT-2-Give/328506206146

like FundRazr. is there any tutorials or resources to build such apps? i have been googling my heart out but cant come across anything

i have uploaded a screenshot of what im hoping for

http://img214.imageshack.us/img214/6008/screengrab2.png

where do you start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As serg indicated, that's not a Facebook Application proper, but rather just a flash movie loaded as an attachment to a stream message.

The new documentation for stream attachments is located [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments).

Answer (score 0):

It's a flash file posted on a wall as attachment. You were able to do this with old rest api, but not with new one. That flash probably contains facebook api and then goes from there.

Sorry if it's not much help...